# Sonoluminescence in a substance that is less dense than air, inside air?

Tags: visible-light, acoustics, atomic-physics

If it is possible to create [sonoluminescense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoluminescence)
 in a liquid because it is denser than the air inside the bubble wouldn't you theoretically be able to create the same effect using a substance that is less dense than air, inside air? But with higher light and heat output because the spaces between the molecules would be greater?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to this question is fairly simple: in order for a bubble to form, we need *surface tension*. ([See related question on Chemistry Stack-Exchange, here.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42038/do-surfactants-exist-in-a-gas-phase)) Thus we need a gas inside a liquid for a bubble to form.  Without a bubble to vibrate, sonoluminescence cannot occur.